# executing RSYNC in jenkins

Tags: linux, jenkins, continuous-integration, web-deployment, jenkins-plugins

Hello everyone so I'm trying to deploy my code to a remote server.. so far I've tried with

- Publish over SSH Plugin :  But the problem is that Im unable to keep the files  permissions
- Rsync command witch I think is better cause of the file permission, the only problem with this is that I don't know how to set the password for it to work automatically

this is what I get

```
[JenkinsBuild] $ /bin/sh -xe /var/lib/jenkins/tmp/hudson4646064064846581974.sh
+ rsync -PSauve ssh --exclude=JenkinsBuild app bower.json config gruntfile.js karma.conf.js LICENSE.md Makefile node_modules package.json Procfile protractor.conf.js public README README.md server.js john@192.168.2.10:/srv/dp/prod
Host key verification failed.
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(600) [sender=3.0.6]
```

any ideas what I'm doing wrong here 
?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way is to copy your local public ssh key to the remote host. Then authentication is done via your key and not by password

simply run ssh-copy-id user@host on your jenkins.

Then there shouldn't be a problem any more :)

Comment: awesome !!! it worked!!!! alright actually I had to log in as  Jenkins and then run the ssh-copy command with the specific user Credentials that I was planing to use... Thanks :D